# ios: delete rows in table view when swiping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have a table view with many sections and any section with many rows. i want to delete a row when i swipe on this cell, but it's complicated to get it swiping, it looks like sometimes it's not getting the call to the specific method. i've implemented 3 methods, tableview can edit row at index path, tableview editing style for row at index path and tableview commit editing style but some times when i do the swipe action, method editing style for row at index path is not called. is it any special reason?

Comment: Do you have any other gesture recognizers on that view controller?

Comment: it sounds like you aren't staying on the cell long enough for it to realize you have selected a cell before you swipe.  then it would be a swipe but without a selected cell to reference.

Comment: @Jacob i do have another gesture recognizer, it detects tap on section header to collapse or to expand the header, besides that, this view controller has a parent view controller which respond to actions like reveal a side menu.

Comment: @luisjd yea that is the problem. I have had that issue before. You cannot use that menu with the gesture recognizer and then try to swipe to delete a cell.

Comment: @Jacob is there a way to add a gesture to every cell that responds to longpress and delete that row?